# jQuery UI accordion destroy not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, destroy

I've hit a problem deleting the accordion widget when the window is resized above a set point.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 and the jQuery UI 1.9.2.

This is my code:

```
/*
* Detect browser size and add accordian on page (at load) if necessary
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();  
    if (window_width <= 767){
        $("div.innernav ul.menu").accordion({ 
            header: '.separator',
            animated: 'slide',
            event: "click",
            heightStyle: "content",
            icons: { "header": false, "headerSelected": false } ,
            collapsible: true, 
            active: false,
        });
    }
});
/*
* Detect browser size on resize and add/remove accordian
*/
$(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();
    if (wi <= 767){
        $("div.innernav ul.menu").accordion({ 
            header: '.separator',
            animated: 'slide',
            event: "click",
            heightStyle: "content",
            icons: { "header": false, "headerSelected": false } ,
            collapsible: true, 
            active: false,
        });
    } else if (wi >= 768){
        $("div.innernav ul.menu").accordion("destroy");
    }
});
```

The code works and my accordion is only active when window width is smaller than 768px but I get an:

`Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialisation; attempted to call method 'destroy'`

It seems this error makes other code I have on the page bork so I could do with removing this error.  I'm a javascript/jQuery newbie so would really appreciate a helping hand.

Many thanks!

Comment: I get the sense it's trying to destroy the accordion with each shift in the window size, even though it's already destroyed? So maybe you want to test for existence before killing it...`} else if (wi >= 768 && $("div.innernav ul.menu .ui-accordion").length){`? (I'm thinking `$("div.innernav ul.menu .ui-accordion")` will be the appropriate selector to get the accordion created by `$("div.innernav ul.menu").accordion(...)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your ready function into a separate function.

Within the else portion:

```
$("div.innernav ul.menu").empty();
```

Then just reifill the ul menu the same as the ready function.

Comment: Thanks Dave - That would indeed empty my UL!  However I need the content to stay where it is.  In the end I rewrote the functions with the help of this stack overflow question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733132/check-if-widget-is-available-before-running-jquery-function)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I re wrote the functions using an if statement to check if the widget is actually active on the element: [Check if Widget is Available Before Running Jquery Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733132/check-if-widget-is-available-before-running-jquery-function)

Here is the finished code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var element = $('div.innernav ul.menu');
    if($(window).width() < 768){
        element.accordion({ header: '.separator', animated: 'slide', event: "click", heightStyle: "content", icons: { "header": false, "headerSelected": false }, collapsible: true, active: false});
    } 
    else {
        element.accordion = false;
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() > 767) {
            element.find('.item').removeAttr('style');
            if(element.accordion) {
                element.accordion('destroy');
                element.accordion = false;
            }
        } 
        else {
            element = $('div.innernav ul.menu');
            element.accordion({ header: '.separator', animated: 'slide', event: "click", heightStyle: "content", icons: { "header": false, "headerSelected": false }, collapsible: true, active: false});
        }
    });
});
```